# How to fetch images from database in base64_encode in php

Tags: php, database, image, base64, fetch

Thank you all in advance....
I am doing a project in which I have a field to store the image. In that form, the image uploaded is completed with croppie plugin. and I stored the data in base 64 encodings. But I cannot fetch it to a page called view.php but the images are fetched to the form after cropping.

Please help me to figure it out the mistake that I have done

```
<tbody>
    <?php
    $no = 1;
    $data = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `register`  WHERE app_registration IS NULL   ORDER BY `app_id` DESC ");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['app_id'] ?></td>
            <?php if (!empty($row['image_reference_id'])) {
                $data1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `photo_table`  WHERE image_unique_id = '" . $row['image_reference_id'] . "'");
                $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data1)
                ?>
                <td><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['images']).'"/></td>
            <?php } else {
                ?>
                <td><img src="../images/<?php echo $row['app_image'] ?>" style="width: 100px;     height: 100px;"></td>
            <?php } ?>
            <td><?php echo $row['app_name'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['app_mobile_no_1'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Note: In db the images are in Long Blob

Comment: It's already encoded you say and you need to echo it `<?php echo $row['images'] ?>` maybe...

Comment: Am not sure about your concatenating `"data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['images']).'" `

Comment: the images are in long blob

Comment: Right, but the problem is that you're trying to call PHP code outside of PHP context here: `<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['images']).'"  />`

Comment: So what I to do ?? I wanted to display that image in a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the following:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['images']).'"  />
```

to

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64, <?php base64_encode($row['images']);?>"  />
```

Comment: Thank you @ikyuchukov..                                                                                                                        <img src="data:image/jpg;base64, <?php echo  base64_encode($row['images']);?>"  />